# Saving XML files locally in the background of the program

Tags: xml, file, actionscript-3, flash, air

i am working on a as3 program witch runs in adobe air.
I have created an XML object.

```
var settings:XML = new XML( <objects /> );
```

Now i want to save this XML into a file locally in a directory.

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference;
file.save( settings, "settings.xml" );
```

But only a dialog box opens, where i can choose the directory for the file.
My question is now how to save the Xml file in a specific directory in the background of the program. I am using Air so i don't need to worry about security errors.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [`FileStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) classes to save to a file in AIR (`FileReference` is mostly for the web browser, which is much more limited). Example:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("mydir/output.xml");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes(xml.toXMLString());
fileStream.close();
```

Tip: You don't need to use the XML constructor, you can [assign an XML literal to an XML object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f95.html):

```
var settings:XML = <objects/>
```